# Unable to open Adobe Reader I installed through Wine

Tags: wine, adobe

I have installed **Adobe Reader** through *Wine*. It created a shortcut on desktop, `adobe reader.desktop`. How can I open it? I cannot open it directly.

Comment: Are you in desperate need to use *Adobe Acrobat Reader*? The default document reader application in Ubuntu (*Evince*) is generally enough for most needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use adobe reader. It uses a lot of system resources. There are plenty of alternatives in Ubuntu. Foxit reader, PDFTK.

Comment: While a useful comment, this does not address the question. There are plenty of cases where institutions demand functionality which only Adobe's own software supports.  And Ubuntu is supposed to be able to install Adobe Reader, most recently through snap (and it does not work for me).